# How does GTK+ deal with pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, gtk

So I'm programming an application in GTK+ in C++ (I should probably be using GTKmm, but I'm not) and with GTK+ all widgets and such are pointers which isn't really ideal, but it doesn't make programming really any more difficult.  However, what happens to those pointers when the window is closed?  Does GTK+ pull a Java and garbage collect all of the pointers to gpointers?  And if it doesn't, how can I access the method that is used by GTK+ to close the window and the program to delete the pointers myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation, you will see that Gtk pointers are all derived from gobjects. Consult the docs on `g_object_ref` and `g_object_unref` but, basically, they hold a count of how many copies are being held. If `g_object_unref` results in a usage count of zero then the object is automatically deleted.

Creating the window returns an object. Telling it to close will remove the displayed bits but calling `g_object_unref` will delete it and all embedded objects. Unless, of course, there is another copy of it, in which case it will remain in existence until `uref()` is called again.

Comment: So is it e necessary to call g_object_unref after closing the window?

Comment: Destroying a widget frees it.

Comment: Not so. If the widget is, for example, a dialog loaded from resources then the resource keeps a copy of it for the next time it is requested. Closing the dialog destroys the window but not the object. If in doubt, try it. It will throw an error if you try to release it too many times (although maybe not until the program exits).

Answer (score 2):

Please read points 1.4 ("How does memory management work in GTK+? Should I free data returned from functions? ") and 1.5 ("Why does my program leak memory, if I destroy a widget immediately after creating it ?") of the GTK+ 3 [common questions](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-question-index.html).

GTK uses a reference counter to know when an GObject-derived object (like all widgets) needs to be destroyed. This way for example, destroying a top level window destroys all the widgets it contains.